# How to make an Eclipse RCP Product version number available in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, eclipse-rcp

I'd like to use the version number defined in an Eclipse product definition file available in Jenkins with a variable so I could use it to automatically tag my builds. How could I do this, maybe with Buckminster?

Comment: What method do you use to build your RCP? Buckminster & Headless PDE build?

Comment: Yes, I use Buckminster & Headless PDE.

Comment: I'm using tycho, which does this automatically